# getActivity Warning in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm using this code on fragment before, and i want to use this code in Activity, but when error came on getActivity()
this my code

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), exerciseList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
// Showing progress dialog before making http request
pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
pDialog.show();
```

Comment: because in activity you can use getApplicationContext() or YourActivity.this

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getActivity()` method on `Activity`. Replace `getActivity` with `this` (or, if needed, `TheNameOfYourActivityClass.this`, where `TheNameOfYourActivityClass` is the name of your activity class).

Answer (score 1):

change `getActivity()` to `this` or `ActivityName.this`

Comment: Thanks for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
getActivity method is not resolve in Activity.You can use getApplicationcontext.
```